# Django: AttributeError when I try to delete a user

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've got a funny error when I try to delete a user from the admin pages (Django 1.5):

`AttributeError at /admin/teaching/student/5/delete/`

`'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'`

followed by a long Traceback I don't understand, ending with a complaint about

```
line 43 in .../site-packages/django/utils/html.py in escape:
return mark_safe(force_text(text).replace('&', '&amp;').replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;').replace('"', '&quot;').replace("'", '&#39;'))
```

but `text` is just the string: `Error in formatting: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found`. So `force_text` is returning a tuple? What's that got to do with my models? I'm confused.

My users are students, and each Student model is has a OneToOneField with the User model, so I guess the corresponding Student object has to be deleted as well. I can delete the User from the shell with no problem at all (and the Student object disappears as well).

Edit: here's the `Student` model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    start_year = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name,

    def user_email(self):
        return self.user.email
```

Comment: Do you have any kind of admin form or some overriding? It is a (funny / pain in the...) error indeed :)

Comment: Nothing special, I don't think. The Student model has a `__unicode__` method that returns `self.name`, and a `user_email` method that returns `self.user.email` for the `StudentAdmin` `list_display`. The only thing I think I might have done different is manually add the field `token` to the Student model's database table (but I ran manage.py syncdb OK).

Comment: Can you post the `Student` model to see if there's something wrong there?

Comment: OK - I see it now! (I'm sure you do too!) Thanks for making me look more closely at this! Sorry to take up your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spotted! If it's not a typo, the trailing comma in your `__unicode__` return clause is making it return a `tuple` so that's the error you're getting.

```
def __unicode__(self):
    # note the tralining comma
    #return self.name,
    #should be like this (no comma)
    return self.name
```

Hope this works!