# 'Model' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, django

I'm using a custom user model `TrackUser` in a Django 1.6 application. When I want to delete a user in the Adminpanel i get this error:

> 'TrackUser' object has no attribute 'replace'

I've looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776888/django-attributeerror-when-i-try-to-delete-a-user) and even though our traceback both end on `../django/utils/html.py` i don't find the solution for my problem.

**Model**

```
class TrackUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    #User data
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    tel_number = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    #User options
    #True for first_name last_name
    #False for last_name first_name
    full_name_order = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=True)

    #Django necessities
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    #Sales fields
    percentage_of_sales = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    objects = UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('user_detail', args=[self.pk])

    def get_full_name(self):
        if self.full_name_order:
            order = (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        else:
            order = (self.last_name, self.first_name)
        return "%s %s" % order

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.get_full_name()
```

**Traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/users/trackuser/18/delete/

Django Version: 1.6.5
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'clients',
 'contracts',
 'projects',
 'products',
 'users',
 'project_settings',
 'south')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/jghyllebert/Documents/projects/nuntra/trackapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/jghyllebert/Documents/projects/nuntra/trackapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  432.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/jghyllebert/Documents/projects/nuntra/trackapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/jghyllebert/Documents/projects/nuntra/trackapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/jghyllebert/Documents/projects/nuntra/trackapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  198.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/jghyllebert/Documents/projects/nuntra/trackapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/jghyllebert/Documents/projects/nuntra/trackapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/jghyllebert/Documents/projects/nuntra/trackapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/Users/jghyllebert/Documents/projects/nuntra/trackapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  371.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/jghyllebert/Documents/projects/nuntra/trackapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in delete_view
  1457.             [obj], opts, request.user, self.admin_site, using)
File "/Users/jghyllebert/Documents/projects/nuntra/trackapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py" in get_deleted_objects
  137.     to_delete = collector.nested(format_callback)
File "/Users/jghyllebert/Documents/projects/nuntra/trackapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py" in nested
  191.             roots.extend(self._nested(root, seen, format_callback))
File "/Users/jghyllebert/Documents/projects/nuntra/trackapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py" in _nested
  174.             children.extend(self._nested(child, seen, format_callback))
File "/Users/jghyllebert/Documents/projects/nuntra/trackapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py" in _nested
  176.             ret = [format_callback(obj)]
File "/Users/jghyllebert/Documents/projects/nuntra/trackapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py" in format_callback
  130.                                obj)
File "/Users/jghyllebert/Documents/projects/nuntra/trackapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/html.py" in format_html
  79.     args_safe = map(conditional_escape, args)
File "/Users/jghyllebert/Documents/projects/nuntra/trackapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/html.py" in conditional_escape
  71.         return escape(text)
File "/Users/jghyllebert/Documents/projects/nuntra/trackapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  203.             return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/jghyllebert/Documents/projects/nuntra/trackapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/html.py" in escape
  39.     return mark_safe(force_text(text).replace('&', '&amp;').replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;').replace('"', '&quot;').replace("'", '&#39;'))

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/users/trackuser/18/delete/
Exception Value: 'TrackUser' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: The onl thing I can think of is, if either `first_name` or `last_name`  is empty, but you do not have a `null` clause though.

Comment: Both are filled in. I even tried changing `__unicode__` to return the email. But, the same error persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem only appeared when a `TrackUser` was linked to another model.

In one of these models I changed the `__unicode__` from

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user
```

to

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.get_full_name()
```

which solved the problem